# Load table where I want it from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm very new to codeigniter but getting there. I've got a page that's loaded via the code below. I've worked out how to generate a html table from sql statement as you'll see, but this way it plonks it at the top of the page. How do I make it render the table at the point i've marked in a comment?

**Routes.php**

```
$route['users/list'] = 'users/listu';
```

**controllers/users.php**

```
public function listu()
    {
        $this->load->library('table');

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

        echo $this->table->generate($query);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('users/list');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

**views/users/list.php**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">

                <!-- Categories -->
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="no-padding">
                        <span class="title">Menu</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group list-categ">
                        <a href="item" class="list-group-item">Item</a>
                        <a href="item" class="list-group-item">Item</a>
                        <a href="item" class="list-group-item">Item</a>
                        <a href="item" class="list-group-item">Item</a>
                        <a href="item" class="list-group-item">Item</a>
                        <a href="item" class="list-group-item">Item</a>
                        <a href="item" class="list-group-item">Item</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Categories -->

            </div>

            <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                <span class="title">List Users</span>
                    <!-- I want to put the table here -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out

**Controllers/users.php**

```
public function listu()
    {
        $this->load->library('table');

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT firstname, surname, email FROM users");

        $data['table_users'] = $this->table->generate($query);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('users/list', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

and in the markup:

```
<?php echo($table_users) ?>
```